# Is it possible to use CSS to align these divs/spans in a table-like manner? (While still retaining continuity)

Tags: javascript, css

I have

```
<div class='line'> 
  <div class='chord_line'> 
    <span class='chord_block'></span> 
    <span class='chord_block'>E</span> 
    <span class='chord_block'>B</span> 
    <span class='chord_block'>C#m</span> 
    <span class='chord_block'>A</span> 
  </div> 
  <div class='lyric_line'> 
    <span class='lyric_block'></span> 
    <span class='lyric_block'>Just a</span> 
    <span class='lyric_block'>small-town girl</span> 
    <span class='lyric_block'>living in a</span> 
    <span class='lyric_block'>lonely world</span> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

(Excuse me for not being too familiar with proper css conventions for when to use div/spans)

I want to be able to display them so that each `chord_block` span and `lyric_block` span is aligned vertically, as if they were left-aligned and on the same row of a table.  For example:

```
  E      B               C#m         A
  Just a small-town girl living in a lonely world
```

(There will often be cases where an empty chord block is matched up to non-empty lyric block, and vice-versa.)

I'm completely new to using CSS to align things, and have had no real understanding/experience of CSS aside from changing background colors and link styles.  Is this possible in CSS?  If not, how could the div/class nesting structure be revised to make this possible?  I could change the spans to divs if necessary.

Some things I cannot use:

- I can't change the structure to group things by a `chord_and_lyric_block` div (and have their width stretch to the length of the lyric, and stack them horizontally), because I couldn't really **copy/select the lyrical lines continuously in their entirety**, which is extremely critical.
- I'm trying to avoid a table-like solution, because this data is not tabular at all.  The chord line and the lyric line are meant to be read as one continuous line, not a set of cells.  Also, apart from the design philosophy reasons, I think it might have the same problems as the previous thing bullet point.

If this is possible, what div/span attributes should I be using?  Can you provide sample css?

If this is not possible, can it be done with javascript?

EDIT: I'm sorry I wasn't clear at the start, but I would like a solution that allows both the chord line and the lyric line to be "selectable" and continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Original Attempt...* ---> **[CSS Tables Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/SFBq8/4/)**

```
div.line {
     display:table;   
}

div.line > div {
     display:table-row;   
}

div.line > div span {
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;   
}
```

For empty blocks, place html entity for non-breaking space as their contents. This should do what you want, if not, then I may have misunderstood.

**SPECIAL NOTE:** Compatibility for display:table-* is limited. [More information](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

**NEW EXAMPLE: Quite sure this is what you are looking for.** ---> 
**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/v3yqr/8/)**

**CSS**

```
.block {
    margin-top:1.5em;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.block .chord {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.8em;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="chord"></div>
    <div class="lyric"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="chord">E</div>
    <div class="lyric">Just a</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="chord">B</div>
    <div class="lyric">small-town girl</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="chord">C#m</div>
    <div class="lyric">living in a</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="chord">A</div>
    <div class="lyric">lonely world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually is exactly the result I am looking for :)  Although it was a bit unclear which demonstration and which code was the one you were actually presenting.  But I think it works really well.  I hope you don't mind, though, if I save my checkmark for a couple days to see if a solution with higher compatibility exists.  Until then, I will implement this.

Comment: The new example doesn't give consistent lyrics rows, it's effectively what I did in my answer. The original attempt results effectively in a table but it's the best way to go without Javascript.

Comment: Hey Pekka. I do see the similarities. The weakness of yours is displayed here: http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/wvDKP/3/ and here: http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/wvDKP/5/ ... compared to: http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/v3yqr/10/. That said, there is a fundamental weakness in mine: display:inline-block is not compatible with IE7, but this can be fixed with: http://www.kollerat.com/cms/index.php/Web-admin/HTML/IE7-and-inline-block.html. Cheers!

Comment: I misread your answer; the original attempt is what I was looking for.  Your second answer is more or less the same answer as other people have given, and falls to the same problem =/ (see bold part of answer)

Comment: Hey Justin, I replaced it shortly after I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked once, and the only workable solution was indeed a combined "chords and lyrics" block (with the chords having a combination of `position: absolute` and `position: relative`). It's the only way I can think of if you want this to work reliably and in edge cases like different font sizes and so on.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvDKP/)

Now this doesn't do exactly what you need: It doesn't allow continuous selection of lyrics. But I can think of two general directions to extend it.

**A) Chords as background images:** If the Chord symbols

```
C# E# Em Am
```

could be background images instead of actual text, you could use my code example and give the `chord_block` class a `background-image` of whatever Chord is in question. The image would have to contain the Chord (e.g. `Em`) as text. The upside is that this keeps the "lyrics line" intact. The downside is that this is not accessible, not resizable, and possibly problematic in print because many browsers don't show background images when printing.

**B) Using jQuery:** Using the approach shown in the JSFiddle, you have elements of the class `chord_block` that are already in the correct position. It should be half-way easy to use jQuery to create a new element on the fly, and add it to the document at the x/y position of each `chord_block` but outside the line, so you can still select the whole lyrics line without interference.

Comment: Even though it does not answer my question 100%, I appreciate your answer. It was actually one of the first things I thought about, but I realized that I didn't even know how to implement that in CSS, heh, so thanks for some education.

Comment: @Justin you're welcome. I just updated it with two ways that could make it work the way you need. I have to go now so I can't elaborate on the jQuery approach - I would have to experiment myself. One of the resident jQuery Gurus might be able to tackle this

Answer (score 0):

It looks interesting to me so I just searched over it and find following article that is discussing similar problem:

[Create a table using CSS](http://mywebdunia.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/create-a-table-using-css/)

I checked it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MdzDp/

I think you need to use **DIVs** and **SPANs** instead of **ULs** and **LIs** here.

Comment: This doesn't really change his basic predicament - it's not different from using a `table` element, it just uses different HTML elements for it

Answer (score 0):

here's a crappy way to do it... i'd try more, but christmas dinner is served :)

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div.line {width:100%;}
div.line div.chord_line div.chord_block, div.line div.lyric_line div.lyric_block {width:20%; float:left;}
div.lyric_line {clear:left;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='line'> 
  <div class='chord_line'> 
    <div class='chord_block'>...</div> 
    <div class='chord_block'>E</div> 
    <div class='chord_block'>B</div> 
    <div class='chord_block'>C#m</div> 
    <div class='chord_block'>A</div> 
  </div> 
  <div class='lyric_line'> 
    <div class='lyric_block'>...</div> 
    <div class='lyric_block'>Just a</div> 
    <div class='lyric_block'>small-town girl</div> 
    <div class='lyric_block'>living in a</div> 
    <div class='lyric_block'>lonely world</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT:

if you're open to structural changes, here you go:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#chord_block {float:left; padding:2px; text-align:left;}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chord_block"> 
    <div id="chord"></div>
    <div id="lyric"></div>
</div>

<div id="chord_block"> 
    <div id="chord">E</div>
    <div id="lyric">Just a</div>
</div>

<div id="chord_block"> 
    <div id="chord">B</div>
    <div id="lyric">small-town girl</div>
</div>

<div id="chord_block"> 
    <div id="chord">C#m</div>
    <div id="lyric">living in a</div>
</div>

<div id="chord_block"> 
    <div id="chord">A</div>
    <div id="lyric">lonely world</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not bad! But the elements suffer from fixed width... That is the tough nut to crack in this thing

Comment: Thanks! note to OP: you'll have to figure out how badly you want that blank div to expand. you can do it, but mind doesn't expand it.

Answer (score 0):

let the down-voting begin ...

as much as I love css, sometimes tables are worth using.

let me clarify, if you can pull it off with css and div's, it's all good; but if you have to spend hours trying to figure the simplest (with tables) layout out -- I think you're wasting your (and your client's) time and money.

Comment: I agree. However, tables will not solve the problem. The problem is that the space between the lines of lyrics cannot be spaced correctly without padding, which is unpredictable in an environment where font sizes may change. It would make the text difficult to read.